# Not pushing duplicate object in array

Tags: angularjs

I have a json skills , I need to multiselect the skills from dropdown `model.skills` , I use `multipleSkills()`to push the selected values in `arrayvalues[]`, but I should not push duplicate values into `arrayvalues`.

Json :

```
var skills = 
[{"name":{"skillId":1,"skillName":"JAVA"}},
{"name":{"skillId":2,"skillName":"C"}},
{"name":{"skillId":3,"skillName":"DEVOPS"}},
{"name":{"skillId":4,"skillName":"ANGULAR JS"}},
{"name":{"skillId":41,"skillName":"drupal"}},
{"name":{"skillId":42,"skillName":"backbone js"}},
{"name":{"skillId":43,"skillName":"nodejs"}},
{"name":{"skillId":44,"skillName":"phone gap"}},
{"name":{"skillId":45,"skillName":"scala"}},
{"name":{"skillId":46,"skillName":"spark"}}]
```

html:

```
<input class="form-control1" type="text" name="skills" placeholder="Core Skills"
       ng-model="model.Skills"  ng-focus="skillsforJobs(model.Skills)" 
       typeahead ="skill as skill.name.skillName for skill in skills | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:10"
       typeahead-on-select="multipleSkills(model.Skills)"
       ng-minlength =1 />
```

JS:

```
    $scope.arrayvalues = [];
    $scope.multipleSkills = function(data){
        if($scope.arrayvalues.length <1){
              $scope.arrayvalues.push(data);
          } else if($scope.arrayvalues.length > 0){
             if($scope.arrayvalues.indexOf($scope.model.Skills) == -1) {                
              if($scope.model.Skills != ""){
                   for( var i=0; i<$scope.arrayvalues.length;i++){

              $scope.arrayvalues[i].name.skillId.indexOf( data.name.skillId){
              $scope.arrayvalues.push(data);
                                  $scope.model.Skills = "";

                    }

                    }

        } 

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

please refer this github project.
[AngularJS Dropdown Multiselect](https://github.com/dotansimha/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect)

html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="angularjs-dropdown-multiselect.js"></script>            
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
           <div ng-dropdown-multiselect="" options="example1data" selected-model="example1model"></div>    
            </div>
```

js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['angularjs-dropdown-multiselect']);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

});
```